# ls not dereferencing symlink directories by default

Tags: macos, shell, command-line, zsh, oh-my-zsh

When I `ls` a symlink to a directory, `ls` just echoes the directory name.

```
➜  java-tutorial git:(main) ls -al
...
lrwxr-xr-x   1 josalvatorre  staff  124 Jul  9 16:17 bazel-bin -> /private/var/tmp/_bazel_josalvatorre/0614f10b8ea3a5a2198fe449cfe635ce/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/darwin_arm64-fastbuild/bin
...

➜  java-tutorial git:(main) ls /private/var/tmp/_bazel_josalvatorre/0614f10b8ea3a5a2198fe449cfe635ce/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/darwin_arm64-fastbuild/bin
ProjectRunner                    ProjectRunner.jar-0.params       ProjectRunner.jdeps              _javac
ProjectRunner-native-header.jar  ProjectRunner.jar-1.params       ProjectRunner.runfiles           external
ProjectRunner.jar                ProjectRunner.jar_manifest_proto ProjectRunner.runfiles_manifest

➜  java-tutorial git:(main) ls bazel-bin
bazel-bin
```

Going off memory, I'm almost certain that this is not normal behavior. It's led to unexpected behavior when I enter commands I find online. What's going on here?

I'm using zsh on an M1 Mac. I use `oh-my-zsh`.

### Follow-Up

A few helpful people pointed out there there are dereferencing options `-H` and `-L` that do the trick. How would I make this the default behavior?

Comment: On my computer `ls` does dereference symlinks but perhaps it depends on some settings or on the OS. Try the option `-L`. If that doesn't help, type `ls --help` and search for the word "symbolic". There is a few options you can try.

Comment: You may have an `ls -H` alias elsewhere? Try this: `ls -H bazel-bin`

Comment: Interesting. Both `ls -L bazel-bin` and `ls -H bazel-bin` worked. What's the reason? I'm looking up those options right now.

Comment: Oh ok. They both dereference symlinks. I guess my follow-up is: how do I make that the default behavior?

Comment: What do you mean by **default behaviour**? You certainly don't want to change the behaviour of `ls` globally, since this might break existing programs. If you only thinking about your personal use on the command line, define an alias or function in you .zshrc for this purpose. You can also name it `ls`, but I would find this confusing. You could name it for instance `l`, i.e. `alias l='ls -L' `

Comment: @user1934428 I've just checked what `type ls` returns for my user account and it is "ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'". I haven't set it myself. It is system default. So I would say customizing a command by aliasing to the same name is not unheard of.

Comment: @NO_NAME : There is no system default for aliases. There must be a definition of this kind in one of your startup files. I am also aware that some people use alias to overwrite an existing name. I just mentioned that I recommend against it, because you always have to be aware of a redefinition. For the same reason, I avoid naming a program I write in the same way as a standard utility. But of course this is something everyone needs to decide for himself.

Comment: @user1934428 Based on other examples online, I thought that `ls` would dereference by default and that my behavior was the result of hidden customization. For me, `type ls` yields `ls is an alias for ls -G`. After removing the alias, I got the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that `ls` was aliasing `ls -G`. I just had to run `unalias ls`.

```
➜  java-tutorial git:(main) ✗ unalias ls        
➜  java-tutorial git:(main) ✗ type ls
ls is /bin/ls
➜  java-tutorial git:(main) ✗ ls bazel-bin 
ProjectRunner                           ProjectRunner.jar-1.params              ProjectRunner.runfiles_manifest         libgreeter-hjar.jdeps                   libgreeter.jar-1.params
ProjectRunner-native-header.jar         ProjectRunner.jar_manifest_proto        _javac                                  libgreeter-native-header.jar            libgreeter.jar_manifest_proto
ProjectRunner.jar                       ProjectRunner.jdeps                     external                                libgreeter.jar                          libgreeter.jdeps
ProjectRunner.jar-0.params              ProjectRunner.runfiles                  libgreeter-hjar.jar                     libgreeter.jar-0.params                 src
➜  java-tutorial git:(main) ✗ ls -G bazel-bin 
bazel-bin
```

As some other folks mentioned, you could also force dereferencing via `-H` and `-L`.

Comment: Why do you unalias the alias? If you don't need the alias, wouldn't it make more sense to remove the alias definition from your startup files?

Comment: Good point. I couldn't find it in my startup files, so I added the unalias command to my `.zshrc` file.

Comment: Just my personal opinion: Since the zsh startup files are completely under your control and basically contain your configurations of zsh and your desired environment, I would find it creepy if there is something going in them which I don't fully understand ....

Comment: @user1934428 I agree. It's pretty frustrating. I gave it a good amount of time, but I don't know how else to debug besides looking through the zshrc/profile files in ~ and /etc. Any debugging tips?

Comment: I would not look through the files manually (too easy to miss something), but instead create a new login shell from scratch, with tracing enabled (i.e. `zsh -lx`), save the output to a file, and then use my favorite text editor to search through the file for any invocation of `alias`. Once I find the culprit, I just have to search backwards in order to find the respective command which _sources_ that bit of code, and I have what need to know. Should take all in all less than 10 minutes....